# How to get the value of ckeckbox element from a form submission in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

For some reason when I submit a form I can't get the value of the checked boxes **I don't mean the check value but the value attribute of the HTML element itself**.

This is my element in the parent component :

```
function parent(props){

  const [filterCriteria, setFilterCriteria] = useState([]);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/companies")
      .then((res) => {
        companiesData = res.data.companies;

        setCompanies([...new Set(companiesData.map((item) => item.company))]);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIslLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/categories")
      .then((res) => {
        categoriesData = res.data.categories;

        setCategories([
          ...new Set(categoriesData.map((item) => item.category)),
        ]);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIslLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);


const onFilteringHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     //fun fact the e.target is looped useing "for of" not "for in" although it's an 
       object
    for (const element of e.target) {
      if (element.type === "checkbox" && 
element.checked === true &&
companies.includes(element.value)) {
        setFilterCriteria([...filterCriteria, element.value]);
      }
      if (element.type === "checkbox" && 
element.checked === true &&
categories.includes(element.value)) {
         setFilterCriteria([...filterCriteria, element.value]);
      }
    }
  };


return (
              //this element is in the medal of tother elements but for simplification i 
               removed them
             <FilterBox
            categoriesCriteria={categories}
            settingFilterCriteria={onFilteringHandler}
            companiesCriteria={companies}
             />

)

}
```

This is my element in the child "FilterBox" component :

```
function FilterBox(props) {

       // this is to map the categories into check boxes with values, keys and label
  let categoriesFilters = props.categoriesCriteria.map((category, index) => {
    return (
      <label key={index}>
        {category}
          //this is the value i'm tring to get in the form submition
        <input type="checkbox" value={category} />
      </label>
    );
  });

       // this is to map the categories into check boxes with values, keys and label
  let companiesFilters = props.companiesCriteria.map((company, index) => {
    return (
      <label key={index}>
        {company}
          //this is the value i'm tring to get in the form submition
        <input type="checkbox" value={company} />
      </label>
    );
  });

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={props.settingFilterCriteria}
      className="product_creation_form"
    >
      <div>
        <h5 className="filter_title">Categories</h5>
        {categoriesFilters}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5 className="filter_title">Companies</h5>
        {companiesFilters}
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="form_button">
        Apply
      </button>
      <button type="reset" className="form_button">
        Clear All
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Nowhere is the issue, I can't get the value in this line:

```
setFilterCriteria([...filterCriteria, element.value]);
```

Although the element.value exist on the e.target?

How to do that?

Comment: `categoriesCriteria` & `companiesCriteria` is always an array with strings?

Comment: I tried to play with your code in a sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dan-5jpvf?file=/src/App.js but without knowing of what you're trying to achieve in `filterCriteria` I won't be able to move further much. Do you want to have an array of strings? or maybe objects for each filter type? or maybe some other solution? I assumed that you will hold it in react state, based on your naming convention `setFilterCriteria`

Comment: yes, categoriesCriteria & companiesCriteria are always strings.

in the end the logic needs an array of strings so i can send it to the back end and filter the incuming products with the needed filtring. there are 2 filters: 1- category 2- company

Comment: i edited the code and added a missing line "const [filterCriteria, setFilterCriteria] = useState([]);" i deleted it when trying to clean the code for stack overflow

Comment: your sandbox made it clear somehow, and i was doing right. but the issue was not getting the element value! Rather it became why the setFilterCriteria is not updating the state. Although it works just fine in your code but not in my environment? which is weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FilterBox Component

```
function FilterBox(props) {
  const categoriesFilters = props.categoriesCriteria.map((category, index) => {
    return (
      <label key={index}>
        {category}
        <input type="checkbox" value={category} name={category} />
      </label>
    );
  });

  const companiesFilters = props.companiesCriteria.map((company, index) => {
    return (
      <label key={index}>
        {company}
        <input type="checkbox" value={company} name={company} />
      </label>
    );
  });

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={props.settingFilterCriteria}
      className="product_creation_form"
    >
      <div>
        <h5 className="filter_title">Categories</h5>
        {categoriesFilters}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5 className="filter_title">Companies</h5>
        {companiesFilters}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="form_button">
        Apply
      </button>
      <button type="reset" className="form_button">
        Clear All
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

App Component:

```
function App() {
  const [companies] = React.useState(["companyOne", "companyTwo"]);
  const [categories] = React.useState(["categoryOne", "categoryTwo"]);

  const onFilteringHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const filterCriteria = { companies: [], categories: [] };

    for (const element of e.target) {
      if (element.type === "checkbox" && element.checked) {
        if (companies.includes(element.value)) {
          filterCriteria.companies.push(element.name);
        }
        if (categories.includes(element.value)) {
          filterCriteria.categories.push(element.name);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(filterCriteria);
  };

  return (
    <FilterBox
      categoriesCriteria={categories}
      settingFilterCriteria={onFilteringHandler}
      companiesCriteria={companies}
    />
  );
}
```

I took the liberty to disconnect the initial API loading of the `companies` & `categories` react state arrays and hardcoded them for simplicity. The below code should be enough to send meaningful data to be able to filter out on the backend.

I took the approach with a non-controlled form state, as your code seemed to favour this kind of approach. You can try and keep the filter values in the react state too but I believe this complicates the solution a bit (especially that state update is async) and it seems that you only need to collect the current filters state value on a button press. If however, you need it for some other purposes, then a controlled form state would most likely be needed.

Comment: Thank you, but can you elaborate about the controlled form state?

Comment: The best place to start would be to read [react docs about forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)